# Mean of transformed distribution with random numbers in numerator and denominator

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I'm looking for a general expression for the mean of

$\langle \frac{f \cdot \frac{1}{n}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{f \cdot \frac{1}{n}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n x_i+(1-f)\cdot\frac{1}{m}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^m y_i}\rangle$

where $x_i$, $y_i$ are exponentially distributed with the same mean $\lambda$.

For n=1,2,3 and m=1, I found expressions by simply integrating. However, I don't know how to get an expression for arbitrary $n$, $m$. Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: What is $f$ here? A constant between $0$ and $1$?

Comment: Hi, exactly. $f$ is a constant between 0 and 1.